# Only first image is being shown

Tags: php, image

I have written a simple code to display images. Images are stored in a folder and its name in mysql. But the problem is only first image is being shown as many times as there are total images in db.
Here is my simple code for displaying images:

```
$query = "Select * from admin_images";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());
$i=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($i>=1)
{
    $img = $rows['my_image_name'];
    echo '<img src="../admin_images/$img">';
    $i--;
}
```

Image name is saved in admin_images table in my_image_name field and actual image is stored in admin_images folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fetch the image url through a loop.
For better understanding of the program flow have a look to below code.

```
//Query to select the image url from database.  

$query = "Select * from admin_images"; // Try to use proper column name instead of * 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); // mysql_* functions are depreciated. So try to avoid using this function. 
$i=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($i >=1)
{
 while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $img = $rows['my_image_name'];
    echo '<img src="../admin_images/$img">';

 }// The above loop will terminate when the condition becomes false. And hence, till now you will have printed all your images.
} else {
echo'No image record found!';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to fetch the rows one after the other:

```
$query = "Select * from admin_images";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error()))
{
    $img = $row['my_image_name'];
    echo '<img src="../admin_images/$img">';
    $i--;
}
```